# How to halt jQuery function execution more than once while it's active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using this http://jsfiddle.net/CqAU2/ plugin for an image rotation, but if you click on the box in the fiddle more than once, it will continue rotating as many times as you clicked on it. What I'd like to do is take the `click` action into account only when the box isn't moving. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag that 'locks' the action if it is still animating, and resets the locked flag after the same time as your animation duration (in your case 1000ms):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var degree = 0;
    var locked = false;
    $(".big-ball").click(function () {
        if (!locked) {
            degree += 30;
            $(this).jqrotate(degree, 1000);
            locked = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                locked = false;
            },1000);
        }
    });
});
```

I've updated [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRwq3/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you wanted ?

http://jsfiddle.net/wq6qm/

I added stop() before calling the animation.

```
$(elem).stop().animate({...})
```

What does stop() do ?

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped.

More about stop here: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thanks, but that won't quite do what I need. I want the animation to finish and once it's done that, the user can click on it again and then it will start animating again.

Answer (score 0):

i update your fiddle - i insert a control for prevent two or more click

```
$.fn.jqrotate = function (degrees, speed) {
    if(typeof $.preventTwo !== "undefined" && $.preventTwo == false) return;
    $.preventTwo = false;
    return this.each(function () {
    var elem = this;
    elem.x = $(elem).data('rot')||0;

    $(elem).animate({
        x: degrees
    }, {
      duration : speed,
      step: function( now, fx ) {
        $(fx.elem).css({
              '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                  '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                   '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+now+'deg)',
                      'transform' : 'rotate('+now+'deg)'
         }).data('rot', now);
      },
      complete : function(){
          $.preventTwo = true;
      }
    });

});
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var degree = 0;
    $(".big-ball").click(function () {
        degree += 30;
        $(this).jqrotate(degree, 2000);
    });
});
```

byee...
http://jsfiddle.net/CqAU2/1/